# Regex select everything between last occurrence and next to last occurrence

Tags: regex

```
$string = "some text; other text; more other text; last text"
```

How would one *select* **'more other text'**?
in this example there are *3 semicolons* but some strings may have *more or less*. but **always atleast 2**.

I know `;(?!.*;)` will find the last occurrence.

Comment: Not really, to find the last occurrence just do `/.+;/`, since "greedy" modifiers exists for this in some way...

Comment: What language are you using? It looks like it might be PHP or c#? If it is c# you might be better off using `$string.Split(';')[2]` but that would only work correctly if there is always going to be 4 sections of text. If there are a varying number of sections, you could still use `$string.Split(';').Count()` to find the number of sections, then call `$string.Split(';')[count - 1]`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: do you want the **3rd occurrence** OR the **second-last occurrence** ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
;([^;]*);[^;]*$
```

and grab matched group #1.

Comment: +1 for concise solution that is made possible by the impeccable logic often found in your answers. :) (Now this comment is longer than the answer itself.)

Comment: lol @zx81 Yes its right I didn't explain because answer was simple and demo link had all the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Using lookbehind. This would match the text before the last semicolon,

```
(?<=;)[^;]*(?=;[^;]*$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/11)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# you might be better off using

```
$string.Split(';')[2];
```

But that would only work correctly if there is always going to be 4 sections of text. If there are a varying number of sections, you could still use

```
int count = $string.Split(';').Count();
```

To find the number of sections, then call

```
$string.Split(';')[count - 1];
```

To get the appropriate element.
I hope that makes sense

For PHP it would look like this when there are 4 elements every time.

```
$string = "some text; other text; more other text; last text"
$pieces = explode(";", $string);
echo $pieces[2];
```

When there are varying numbers of semi-colons:

```
$string = "some text; other text; more other text; last text"
$pieces = explode(";", $string);
$count = count($pieces);
echo $pieces[$count - 1];
```